Strategy for cleaning data from multiple sources
I have a table with multiple information referred to the same entity arriving from different data sources.
Let's say the table structure is as follows (the actual table has a lot more columns):
create table dbo.infoBySource
(
    entityId     int
    ,dataSourceId int
    ,col1         varchar(50)
    ,col2         int
    ,constraint pk_infoBySource primary key (entityId, dataSourceId)
)

insert dbo.infoBySource values  
(1 ,1 ,'a' ,null),    
(1 ,2 ,'a2' ,10),    
(2 ,2 ,'c' ,20)

I'd like write a query which removes the dataSourceId field, by keeping the "best" information available (column by column) disregarding null information.
Here the assumption is that different data sources are ordered by "quality priority" (let's assume for simplicity that this priority is given by the dataSourceId value itself)
This is the best solution I've come to:
;with
    info   as
    (select
     a.*
    ,isCol1ToKeep =  case when ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by entityId 
                order by case when a.col1 is null then null else -dataSourceId end desc) = 1 then 1 else 0 end
    
    ,isCol2ToKeep =  case when ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by entityId 
                order by case when a.col2 is null then null else -dataSourceId end desc) = 1 then 1 else 0 end

        from
            dbo.infoBySource a
    )

select
    i.entityId
    ,col1 = max(case when i.isCol1ToKeep = 1 then i.col1 else null end)
    ,col2 = max(case when i.isCol2ToKeep = 1 then i.col2 else null end)

from
    info i

group by i.entityId

But I think my solution is unsatisfactory being difficult to maintain, error prone and possibly inefficient.
Is there a better strategy?

You can probably simplify and use: FIRST_VALUE(colX) OVER(ORER BY case when colX IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ...

If you're using SQL Server 2022 or later, you can use the window function FIRST_VALUE with the IGNORE NULLS option :
WITH info AS (
  SELECT entityId,
     isCol1ToKeep = FIRST_VALUE(col1 ) IGNORE NULLS OVER(PARTITION BY entityId  ORDER BY dataSourceId),
     isCol2ToKeep = FIRST_VALUE(col2 ) IGNORE NULLS OVER(PARTITION BY entityId  ORDER BY dataSourceId)
  FROM dbo.infoBySource
)
SELECT entityId
      ,col1 = max(isCol1ToKeep)
      ,col2 = max(isCol2ToKeep)
FROM info
GROUP BY entityId


I'm using Azure SQL, it works and it is much cleaner than my solution, thanks

Glad to hear I could help :)

I'm successfully using your solution, I'm just wondering how to tell my editor (Azure Data Studio 1.48.1) that this syntax is in fact valid on SQL Azure: it keeps adding a red wavy line under the IGNORE keyword and I can't find where to specify the target SQL dialect

Sorry, I can't help you with that as I've never used Azure
